# Using a list of Tkinter CheckButtons to get values

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Around line 36 in the CreateJson function, I'm trying to use the state of the checkboxes I've created to create a JSON file (I'm aware this is not the best way to create a JSON file ). Anyways I've tried many different ways to read the value of the Checkbox. I've read that using .get() on the Tkinter object works to grab the value, but I've tried that stand-along and on my list here and it does not seem to work. Printing the list shows the object and its locations like so. *<tkinter.IntVar object at 0x000001CD7FB41150>*

````
from itertools import count
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import json
from traceback import print_tb

def openFile():

    filepath = filedialog.askdirectory()

    f = open("Modstext.json","w")
    f.write("\"mods\": [")

    jsonfiles = []
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(filepath):
        for x in files:
            if x.endswith("ServerData.json"):
                jsonfiles.append(os.path.join(dirpath, x))

    counter = 0
    r = [len(jsonfiles)]
    for item in jsonfiles:
        with open(item,encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            var = IntVar()
            Checkbutton(window, text = data["name"],variable = var,onvalue=1,offvalue=0).pack()
            r.append(var)
            counter += 1

    def CreateJson(): 
        counter = 0
        print(r)
        for x in jsonfiles:
            if r[counter] == 1:       
                with open(x,encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
                    data = json.load(file)
                    f.write("\n     {")
                    f.write("\n          \"modsId\":" + "\""+data["id"]+"\",")
                    f.write("\n          \"name\":" + "\""+data["name"]+"\",")
                    f.write("\n          \"version\":" + "\""+data["revision"]["version"]+"\"")
                f.write("\n     },")    
                counter += counter 
            else:
                counter += counter
                pass
        f = open("Modstext.json", "a")
        f.write("\n  ]")
        f.close
    
    button1 = Button(text="Create",command=CreateJson)
    button1.pack()  
    
    f.close()

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x1200")
button = Button(text="Open",command=openFile)
button.pack()
window.mainloop() ```
````

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't see where you try to get values in CreateJson. And Stackoverflow doesn't show line numbers so I don't know which line is `36`

Comment: I don't know how you tried to use `.get()` but you have to use it on every `IntVar` separatelly, and this needs `for`-loop.

Comment: if you want to get value from `IntVar` using `r[counter]` then you have to use `r[counter].get()`

Comment: if `r` has to be list of `IntVar`s then I don't understand why you add `len(jsonfiles)` to this list - in line `r = [len(jsonfiles)]`. And later it can make problem because first element on list  is integer value instead of `IntVar` - and first value need `r[counter]` without `.get()`, and other values needs `r[counter].get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure we totally understand your question. Is this what you are looking for?

```
value = Checkbutton.get()
print(value)
```

The return value will be a yes or a no, or a 1 or 0.